# How to group by date and sum up in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I have tried to find this in google and in here but seems i cant find a decent answer here the problem
what i want i want is i need to get the sum of the total hrs for each day from monday to sunday displaying like this [please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIV0d.jpg)

and my **model** is like this

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_logs
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_logs
end

class TaskLog < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :staff
belongs_to :client
end
```

and my **controller**

```
@hrs_staff_by_client = TaskLog.joins(:staff).joins(:client).joins(:user).select("staffs.full_name AS full_names").select("staffs.position AS positions").select("clients.full_name AS client_names").select("users.email AS emails").select("clients.*, SUM(task_logs.total_hrs) AS today").group("staffs.id, users.id, clients.id")
```

Comment: What is the relation between users and TaskLog? Is a TaskLog only single day by design?

Comment: user has many task logs

Comment: you should edit your question so that readers can see that.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we will group the data by names of days of the week of `TaskLog`:

```
Staff
  .joins(:task_logs)
  .group("GROUP BY to_char(task_logs.created_at, 'dy'), staffs.id")
  .select("SUM(task_logs.total_hrs) AS sum_total_hrs, staffs.id AS staff_id, to_char(task_logs.created_at, 'dy') AS day_string")
```

The result of above query will be: (for example)

```
 sum_total_hrs | staff_id | day_string
---------------+----------+-----------
      50       |     1    |    fri
      45       |     1    |    sat
      20       |     2    |    sat
```

From above result you can join again with `Staff` and other tables to get all columns you need, for example:

```
temp_sql = Staff
      .joins(task_logs)
      .group("GROUP BY to_char(task_logs.created_at, 'dy'), staffs.id")
      .select('SUM(task_logs.total_hrs) AS sum_total_hrs, staffs.id AS staff_id, to_char(task_logs.created_at, 'dy') AS day_string').to_sql

Staff.joins(task_logs: :client)
     .joins("JOIN (#{temp_sql}) AS temp ON temp.staff_id = staffs.id")
```

Comment: the result should be something like this
Full Name | Position | Client Name | Time Worked for the week | Monday  Tuesday  Wednsday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday  Sunday